# Best efficient way to do jquery keyup calculations on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With the jquery `keyup change` function, I've made a calculation box that performs a certain calculation based on the inputs.

But suppose the inputs already have some values when the page loads. What should be the best efficient way to display that calculation result as well if the inputs are not empty when the page loads?

This is the example code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on("keyup change", "#num1, #num2", function() {

        var num1 = $('#num1').val();
        var num2 = $('#num2').val();

        var cal = 20 * num1 * num2;

        $('#result').html('The reslut is ' + cal);

    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Number 1: <input name="num1" id="num1" type="number" value="4"><br>
Number 2: <input name="num2" id="num2" type="number" value="5"><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: You can do something like `$("#num1").trigger("change")` insert this in your `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: trigger change event on load.

Comment: Also note that the `input` event would be better suited to your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trigger it - I use input since it also handles paste

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("input", "#num1, #num2", function() {
    var num1 = $('#num1').val();
    var num2 = $('#num2').val();
    var cal = 20 * num1 * num2;
    $('#result').html('The result is ' + cal);
  });
  $("#num1").trigger("input");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Number 1: <input name="num1" id="num1" type="number" value="4"><br> Number 2: <input name="num2" id="num2" type="number" value="5"><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Alternatively name the function and run it

```js
function calc() {
  var num1 = $('#num1').val();
  var num2 = $('#num2').val();
  var cal = 20 * num1 * num2;
  $('#result').html('The result is ' + cal);
}
$(function() {
  $(document).on("input", "#num1, #num2", calc)
  calc();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Number 1: <input name="num1" id="num1" type="number" value="4"><br> Number 2: <input name="num2" id="num2" type="number" value="5"><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Both of them are very good solutions and each one has some benefits over another depending on the project. But it's great to learn efficient approaches. Thanks again.

Comment: Change (document) to a closer container  selector for even more efficiency - if the fields are on the page at load time no need to delegate